# unresolved external symbol with qt 5.5.1 and visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake, qt5.5

Greeting

I have application made with `QT 4.8.5` and `Visual Studio 2008`. For some reason i need to update my `QT` to `5.5.1` and my `Visual Studio` to `2010`. I downloaded `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1` and build-ed for `Visual Studio 2010`.

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010 -icu -openssl -nomake examples -prefix C:\QT-Compile
nmake
nmake install
```

When i build my solution, I get following errors :

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_ttu_manager.obj
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_vdm_manager.obj
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_wosa_event_listener.obj
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall RPTRManager::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@RPTRManager@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_rptr_manager.obj
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_jptr_manager.obj
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_sptr_manager.obj
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_siu_manager.obj
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cim_manager.obj
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_dep_manager.obj
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_idc_manager.obj
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_pin_manager.obj
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_device_manager.obj
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_bcr_manager.obj
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cam_manager.obj
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cdm_manager.obj
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_controller.obj
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_user_interface.obj
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_ssl_connection_manager.obj
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ)  C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_fit_manager.obj
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_vdm_manager.obj
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_wosa_event_listener.obj
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_jptr_manager.obj
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_sptr_manager.obj
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_siu_manager.obj
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_ttu_manager.obj
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_dep_manager.obj
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z) referenced in function __ehhandler$?startListenSignal@IDCManager@@QAEXVQString@@@Z C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_idc_manager.obj
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_pin_manager.obj
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_rptr_manager.obj
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_bcr_manager.obj
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cam_manager.obj
Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cdm_manager.obj
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_cim_manager.obj
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_controller.obj
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_user_interface.obj
Error   36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __thiscall QObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (__imp_?qt_metacast@QObject@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)    C:\Hashemi\Build\New_ATM\moc_fit_manager.obj
```

Actually there is a lot more, I'm just mentioning some of them.

I know `unresolved external symbol` error is about linker can not finding libraries but as i checked in `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`, All lib directory are imported.

What i'm missing here !!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I ran into this issue too and found that I was running cmake to create a x64 build while pointing at x86 Qt5 dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Before `QT5` i was using following lines in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5 REQUIRED)  
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(project-name
${QT_LIBRARIES}
...)
```

With `QT5` i need to change them to following form.

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Network Sql WebKit Widgets Multimedia) 
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(project-name
    Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql Qt5::WebKit Qt5::Multimedia 
...)
```